# Android Studio - generated PDF not showing drawables correctly

Tags: android-studio, pdf, android-drawable

I'm trying to generate a PDF file in my Android Studio app. Mostly it works fine, but I'm having an issue with the drawables not showing up. I'm not sure whether they're not appearing at all, or whether they're being shown in white.  I've tried changing the tint to black, but that doesn't help.  I've no idea whether this is something I'm doing wrong, or a known issue.  Has anyone else come across it?

The PDF is produced like this:

```
// Create PDF document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
// Create page description
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(content.getWidth(), content.getHeight(), 1).create();

// Start first page - pattern details and chart
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
// Finish page
document.finishPage(page);
```

The onDraw function of the Cell class is:

```
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        float height = canvas.getHeight();
        float width = canvas.getWidth();

        paint.setColor(0xff000000);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(1, 1, width-1, height-1, paint);

        // Drawable has been set up already, as listed below
        if(drawable != null) {
            int b_width = (int) (width - 1);
            int b_height = (int) (height - 1);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                if (mode == MODE_KEY) drawable.setTint(Color.BLACK);
            }
            drawable.setBounds(1, 1, b_width, b_height);
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

and the Drawable is set up like this:

```
        String drawableName = "kps_" + thisSymbol.getSymbolBaseName();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Drawable d;
        if(resourceId != 0) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                d = resources.getDrawable(resourceId, context.getTheme());
            } else {
                d = resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
            }
            thisCell.setDrawable(d);
        }
```

The line 'thisCell.setDrawable(d)' is used to pass the drawable to the Cell class; this also invalidates the Cell, causing it to redraw.

Any pointers?  Or is there a better way to do this?